# Existence of a continuous function on compact hausdorff space where $f(x) =1$ and $f(y)=-1$ with $\|f\|_\infty =1$.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I think from topology, in the space of continuous functions on compact Hausdorff space that maps to the complex numbers, there exists a $f$ such that $f(x) =1$ and $f(y)=-1$ with $\|f\|_\infty =1$ where $x,y$ are distinct points of our compact Hausdorff space. I was wondering why such a function should exist and is the proof of its existence related to Urysohns lemma?

Answer (score 1):

It is an easy consequence of Urysohns' Lemma. There exists a continuous function $g$  with $0\leq g\leq 1$, $g(x)=0$ and $g(y)=1$ (because $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$ are disjoint closed sets. Take $f=1-2g$. Note that $-1 \leq f \leq 1$.